# [Swagger][Android] Best practice when using model generated

Tags: android, swagger, swagger-codegen

My team starting use swagger in our new project. I have a question that should we depend on entities generated from swagger so much in application?

For example:

> "status" is a field of SwaggerUser entity, type is boolean. true is
>   active and false is deactive

If we use SwaggerUser directly from entire application such as:

```
if(user.status){
        //do something
    }else{
        //do something else 
    }
```

it works perfect at the begining.

Few weeks later, system changed, "status" now change to integer.

> 0 is deactive, -1 is deleted, 1 is active

Now we need to refactor every place using the code block above, I think it's very bad. our structure is depending on external thing
So I decide to write my own entity and use mapper to map data from Swagger's entity to my own entity like:

```
class SwaggerUser{
    //other attributes
    boolean status;
}

class MyUser{
    Status status;
}

enum Status{
    ACTIVE(1), DEACTIVE(0), DELETE(-1)
}

class UserMapper{
    public static MyUser map(SwaggerUser swaggerUser){
        //code convert here
        return myUser;
    }
}
```

Now code logic can be like this:

```
swith(status){
    ACTIVE:
        //do smth with active
        break;
    DEACTIVE:
        //do smth with deactive
        break;
    DELETE:
        //do smth with delete
        break;
}
```

I believe with this approach can help us protect our code structure from broken when Swagger's entity changed. I want to share my experience and listen from developer have experience when dealing with this case. If you have any better idea please share. Thanks

Comment: What is a `SwaggerUser` entity ?  _ That is not on the swagger specification: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md

Comment: SwaggerUser is just a example , it can be any thing bro

Comment: In that case I don't think your problem here has anything to do with swagger

Comment: Yes I mean it's not swagger problem. The problem is how android developer (ios or web) can react with changed from swagger. I want to share my best practice with people and listen from developer has experience when dealing with swagger